# Adding values in SQL with Distinction

Tags: sql, aggregation

I have a `customer_id`, `rental_id`, and `amount` all in one table (`payments`). I need to create a report showing the number of rentals a customer has made and the total amount they have spent. So far I have the following query

```
SELECT distinct customer_id, rental_id, amount
FROM payments ORDER BY customer_id
```

I need to assign a rental value per single customer and then show the amount they have spent on all the rentals

Comment: Please share sample data from the table along with the expected output. This will help in providing a proper solution.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1):

select customer_id, count(rental_id),sum(amount) from payments group by customer_id;

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that one row in table represents one customer rent

```
SELECT customer_id, count(*), sum(amount)
FROM tab
GROUP BY customer_id
```